# sql or python solution for getting merging duplicate rows into one in an ordered table and reordering them

Tags: duplicates, sql-order-by, ordereddictionary

Can someone help me do this in SQL in a select statement?
I have a table xyz as follow:

| ColumnID | Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | A |
| 1 | 2 | B |
| 1 | 3 | C |
| 1 | 4 | D |
| 2 | 1 | A |
| 2 | 2 | B |
| 2 | 3 | C |
| 2 | 4 | C |
| 3 | 1 | A |
| 3 | 2 | A |
| 3 | 3 | B |
| 3 | 4 | B |
| 4 | 1 | A |
| 4 | 2 | B |
| 4 | 3 | V |
| 4 | 4 | V |

I want it to change to this:

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | A |
| 2 | B |
| 3 | C |
| 4 | D |
| 1 | A |
| 2 | B |
| 3 | C |
| 1 | A |
| 2 | B |
| 1 | A |
| 2 | B |
| 3 | V |

haven't tried anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution for anyone who has the same question:

```
with abc as (select  columnID, ROW_NUMBER() over (PARTITION by columnID, column_b   ORDER BY columnID) as column_a, column_b 
                from xyz)
    select  row_number() over (partition by columnID order by column_a asc) as column_a, column_b
    from abc where row_num = 1
```